# How to make all links with http or https in static block depending on url

Tags: php, magento

I have used  tag in static block.

so if i use http://www.example.com

my href attribute link should be like http://www.example.com/page1

and if i use https://www.example.com

my href attribute link should be like https://www.example.com/page1

is there any way to do it in magento.

Thanks

Comment: If my answer is right like you commentend, please mark it as correct answer / upvote for others with same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use unsecure url to get http://www.example.com in your static block:

```
{{config path='web/unsecure/base_url'}}
```

and secure url to get https://www.example.com in your static block:

```
{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}
```

If you want to insert conditional logic within the static block, you have to call a template file within your static block and put the logic in there. Use:

```
<block type="core/template" name="block.name" template="path/to/template.phtml"/>
```

Check if current url is secure:

```
if (Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure()) {
    // Your code logic
}
```

Getting unsecure base url within php:

```
Mage::getBaseUrl();
```

Getting secure base url within php:

```
Mage::getUrl('',array('_secure'=>true));
```

Comment: if i use one of the above it will display me only secure or unsecure url. is there any directive available that will help me to use it ones . i dont want to create 2 static block and call it

Comment: i want also do my links dynamic like <a>test1</a> to <a>test2</a>  by static block . so how can i achieve it

Comment: Put also your dynamic html within the phtml template file, together with your php logic.

Comment: i think you are right. i am just asking  because i have already 8 static blocks depending on 8 language. and my client want it editable from his end. and also want http and https on the content of static block. is there any way so my all links become https  ?

Comment: You can't add `dynamic` content in a `static` block. So for your links, it will not work. But if you have static content, this could be edited from static block. For always https, you can use `{{config path='web/secure/base_url'}}` like in my answer, or hardcode it.